# Align an image to the bottom of an ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-imageview, scaletype

I have an image that gets cut from the top as well as the bottom when it is rendered inside an ImageView. I want it to be cut only from the top. Here's an illustration of the problem. Yellow represents the image and blue is the screen viewport covered by an ImageView.

[image]

I have tried FIT_END as scaleType, it didn't help as the image shrinks inside the View and the left portion is left with white space. Also, tried it with adjustViewBounds, there's no change. I don't want the image to shrink.

Edit: Here's my layout, that simply has an ImageView.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

Comment: Can you share designed xml?

Comment: You can have one easy way to do that by adding a top margin  with that...Have you tried that?

Comment: Please share the layout you're working on. At least the `ImageView` portion.

Comment: I have updated my question to include my layout.

Comment: @ReazMurshed That question dealt with TOP_CROP, I was looking for BOTTOM_CROP; but it did help me with my issue. I am marking it as a duplicate. Thanks, for pointing it out.

Comment: Glad to know that you could figure out your problem.